# How can I change WM_CLASS for a WinForms application on Linux?

Tags: .net, winforms, unity-container, x11

I've got a cross-platform .NET app that is using WinForms.

For better compatibility with Unity I'd like to set the `WM_CLASS` property of a WinForms window. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to full sample project here on [bitbucket.org/hindlemail/settingwmclass](https://bitbucket.org/hindlemail/settingwmclass):

> Example project showing how to set the WM_CLASS X11 property for a
>   mono winform application running on Linux. This makes mono winforms
>   applications behave better with the unity + gnome3 window managers.

```
    // Managed struct of XSetClassHint classHint.
    public struct XClassHint
    {
        public IntPtr res_name; 
        public IntPtr res_class;
    }       


    [DllImport ("libX11", EntryPoint="XSetClassHint", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
    public extern static int XSetClassHint(IntPtr display, IntPtr window, IntPtr classHint);


    public static void SetWmClass(string name, string @class, IntPtr handle)
    {           
        var a = new NativeX11Methods.XClassHint { 
                        res_name = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(name), 
                        res_class = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(@class) 
                    };
        IntPtr classHints = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(a));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(a, classHints, true);
          NativeX11Methods.XSetClassHint(NativeReplacements.MonoGetDisplayHandle(),     NativeReplacements.MonoGetX11Window(handle), classHints);           

        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(a.res_name);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(a.res_class);

        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(classHints);
    }
```

The above page has a [download link to the source code](https://bitbucket.org/hindlemail/settingwmclass/get/2fbf3c67c3fc.zip):

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't find that sample project, thanks! However you quoted only a small part of the solution. The `NativeReplacements` class from the sample project is responsible for all the nasty details of how to get the X11 display and window references.